How to correctly do a Multivariate t-Distribution in R
I am working on a statistical analysis in R where I need to do a multivariate t-distribution. Each component of my parameter vector 
β should follow a univariate t-distribution derived from a multivariate setup. The distributions are defined as follows:
β has a k-dimensional t-distribution:
(1,(1/1)Σ1,1)
βi has a t-distribution:
t(β1,i,δ1/α1Σ1,ii,α1)
​
Here is the R code I have written to do this distribution, where I calculate the variance for each component and then attempt to sample using rmvt from the mvtnorm library:
library(mvtnorm) 

n_samples <- 1000  


for (i in 1:length(beta_1)) {
    
    scaled_sigma_i <- (delta_1 / alpha_1) * sigma1[i, i]
    samples_beta_apriori <- rmvt(n = n_samples, sigma = matrix(scaled_sigma_i), df = alpha_1, delta = beta_1[i])

    # Plot histogram for the ith component
    hist(samples_beta_apriori, breaks = 30, freq = FALSE, col = "orange",
         main = paste("Prior Distribution beta_", i, sep = ""),
         xlab = "Value", ylab = "Probability Density")
}


Only use triple backticks to frame code blocks. What is the question here?  Are you getting errors?

Its working but Im not sure if implemented it correctly based on this β has a k-dimensional t-distribution: (1,(1/1)Σ1,1), βi has a t-distribution: t(β1,i,δ1/α1Σ1,ii,α1)​

Given the fact that
β has a k-dimensional t-distribution:

(1,(1/1)Σ1,1)
βi has a t-distribution:
t(β1,i,δ1/α1Σ1,ii,α1)

you are correct in doing it this way. I just adjusted the code slightly
library(mvtnorm)

n_samples <- 1000  
beta_1 <- c(0.5, -0.2, 0.8)  
delta_1 <- 1.5  
alpha_1 <- 3  
sigma1 <- matrix(c(1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1), nrow = 3)
scaled_sigma <- (delta_1 / alpha_1) * sigma1

samples_multivariate_t <- rmvt(n = n_samples, sigma = scaled_sigma, df = alpha_1, delta = beta_1)

for (i in 1:length(beta_1)) {
  samples_beta_i <- samples_multivariate_t[, i]
  
  hist(samples_beta_i, breaks = 30, freq = FALSE, col = "orange",
       main = paste("Prior Distribution beta_", i, sep = ""),
       xlab = "Value", ylab = "Probability Density")
}


which gives you


Don't forget to mark the answer as accepeted to make it disappear from the list of unanswered questions, if it is what you were looking for of course.
